# Check if POST data was sent to page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to check if POST data has been sent to a page. A quick Google search turned up nothing.

```
if(postdataisSent)
{
    //do this
}
else
$items = Gamefarm::where('roost_hen', '=', 1)->paginate(6);
return View::make('gamefarms/index',compact('items'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `if ( Input::has('parameter') )` to check for the existence of a certain parameter in the POST, or you can pass a default into the function, and then test if it's there.

```
$parameter = Input::get('parameter', false);
if ($parameter)
{
    // do something with the data
}
else
{
    // it's not present in the POST
}
```

To check for the presence of any data at all:

```
$data = Input::all();
if (count($data) > 0)
{
    // there is data in the POST
}
else
{
    // there is no data in the POST
}
```

**Note** - You can access the data from [any HTTP verb (GET, POST etc) using the same `Input::get('data')`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input)

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, but I'm not looking for an specific input, I just want to check if a form is submitted to the page

Comment: @jakebalba - lots of options available to you! Updated my answer with one idea.  Take a look at the Laravel docs, they are really rather good: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input